# Generate WFS-T requests

Tags: wfs, java, wfs-t

I want to create WFS-T update/insert/delete requests in my java application. As a result I want to save the requests in XML encoding, as specified by the [OGC standard](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wfs).

Does someone know a library (prefarably Java) which helps to create the WFS-T update/insert/delete requests?..

Answer (score 2):

[GeoTools](http://geotools.org) provides a WFS module that will create WFS-T requests programatically, see http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/data/wfs.html for details.